# How to deploy Maven sites to Artifactory?

Tags: maven, artifactory

We have upgraded from a very old Artifactory (which was 6-7 years old). At the time, due to space limitations, part of the repositories were not handled by Artifactory, but were served over HTTP via the Apache httpd server. The artifacts which were served via Apache httpd, were deployed over SCP. We're trying to migrate everything from SCP to HTTPS. We've migrated pretty much everything. However, we are now left with the Maven sites which were also deployed over SCP and served by Apache.

We would like to migrate all these sites over to Artifactory. Do we need a separate kind of repository for this? I couldn't find how this works in Artifactory. Could somebody please provide an explanation, or a link?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Artifactory has a great support for serving Maven sites (or any static HTML content) directly out of zip (or jar) files. The feature is called "Content Browsing" and you can allow it in the Local Repository settings. Once allowed, you can drill down to the archive to reach an HTML, and it will be served as it was a regular file in Artifactory.

Here's an example: 
http://repo.jfrog.org/artifactory/libs-releases-local/org/artifactory/artifactory-papi/%5BRELEASE%5D/artifactory-papi-%5BRELEASE%5D-javadoc.jar!/index.html

This is a javadocs jar served as a deployed html site.
 Note the `!` when you are entering the artifact.

[Update 08/11/15: Due to [a bug](https://www.jfrog.com/jira/browse/RTFACT-7912), currently this works only in the Pro version. We are working to bring this functionality back to OSS version, where it belongs.]

---

<sup>I am with [JFrog](http://jfrog.com), the company behind [Bintray](https://bintray.com/) and [[artifactory]](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/artifactory), see [my profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/402053/jbaruch) for details and links.</sup>

Comment: Interesting! Out of curiosity, is this implemented using TueZip? Also, would you happen to have a sample Maven project which illustrates using this specifically for Maven Sites? Ours are currently being deployed as exploded web applications and not jars/wars.

Comment: Nope, not with TrueZip. The link I gave you is a sample of this functionality, it works with Maven Site as well.
Since you already have Artifactory installed, just go ahead and deploy a maven site zip to it and see what's happening :)

Comment: As per this page: http://binary-repositories-comparison.github.io/, the site browsing support seems available in the OSS version, right? I mean -- I have enabled "Content Browsing" for the respective repository and the site artifact was successfully deployed. However, when I try accessing it via https://artifactory/artifactory/test-snapshots-local/com/foo/bar/1.0-SNAPSHOT/bar-2.0-20150811.113001-5-site.jar!/docs/index.html, I get a 403 response and in the log file, it is complaining about "Sending HTTP error code 403: Direct resource download from zip requires the Filtered resources add-on".

Comment: Is there some HOWTO/documentation, you would recommend on how to set this up properly?

Comment: Did you enable content browsing? Because otherwise you are trying to download the file from archive (and that's a Pro feature).
Re the docs, see Local Repository setup in the User Guide.

Comment: Yes, I have enabled "Content browsing" for this repository. My site is a `jar`. Is there anything else that needs to be enabled? Once again, this is supported in the OSS version, right? I can browse it via the artifact tree, but the site is not being served.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/86716/discussion-between-carlspring-and-jbaruch).

Comment: We have hit the same problem as our maven site zip/jar artifacts are not browsable.

Comment: @mettw as it turned out, due to a bug, this feature is available only in Pro (although should be in OSS). We'll fix that.

Comment: Thanks for prompt response JBaruch.

Comment: Is the feature abandoned in OSS? It does not work for a [long time](https://www.jfrog.com/jira/browse/RTFACT-9803).