# Artifactory - All Accounts Getting 403 Forbidden on Archive Entry Download

Tags: download, archive, artifactory, http-status-code-403

Recently, the Administrator account (as well as all others) on our Artifactory server has started receiving a 403 forbidden error on [Archive Entry Downloads](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Artifactory+REST+API#ArtifactoryRESTAPI-ArchiveEntryDownload).

This issue is very recent, and only started occurring yesterday. As far as we can tell there was no update to the server, its still running Artifactory OSS 4.12.01. We've tried downloading both through the web UI (which now doesn't have a download button for the artifact entries, even for the Admin) and a RESTful call. Would anyone be able to provide an inkling on where to start looking for why this happened?

Comment: Hi,  does this happen only in one repository or more then one? What do you see in the artifactory.log file,?  The error should have a message or the reason in the log and in the rest api feedback.

Comment: Thank you for the log idea. I went through it over the last couple of days and found this: `2016-10-03 10:07:50,324 [ajp-nio-8019-exec-10] [WARN ] (o.a.r.ArtifactoryResponseBase:107) - Sending HTTP error code 403: Direct resource download from zip requires the Filtered resources add-on.`Considering that in the documentation it does not note this as a Pro feature, it seems they are planning on making this one by putting it into a plugin, and therefore forcing people to buy Pro to get the plugins feature. Thanks for your help though!

Comment: Also found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31880054/how-to-deploy-maven-sites-to-artifactory#comment66509433_31883203

Comment: Hi @Jesse, as far as I know,  working at JFrog,  this should not be a pro feature...  As Baruch stated in the stackoverflow thread you've added it does seem like a bug.

Comment: @Ariel it seems like this issue hasn't been touched in a year. Do you know if its been pushed to the backburner or if its being worked on? Thanks!

Comment: It seems that this was fixed in the past and had a regression. Please find below the Jira ticket to upvote and follow:
'https://www.jfrog.com/jira/browse/RTFACT-9803'